# ATmega328P EEPROM not writing

Tags: c, arduino, avr, arduino-uno, avr-gcc

I'm writing to the ATmega328P EEPROM as follows:

```c
eeprom_write_byte(address, (U8_T) 0);
```

```c
void eeprom_write_byte(void* address, U8_T data)
{
    cli();
    /* Wait for previous write to complete */
    while (TRUE == EECR.bits.EEPE) {
    }

    /* Set erase-and-write mode */
    EECR.bits.EEPM0 = FALSE;
    EECR.bits.EEPM1 = FALSE;

    /* Set up write */
    EEAR.byte = (U8_T) address;
    EEDR.byte = data;

    /* Enable master write */
    EECR.bits.EEMPE = TRUE;
    /* Enable write */
    EECR.bits.EEPE = TRUE;
    sei();
}
```

Where `EECR`, `EEAR`, and `EEDR` are linked as follows:

```
SECTIONS {
  EEAR          = 0x41;
  EEDR          = 0x40;
  EECR          = 0x3F;
  ...
```

`EEMPE` and `EEPE` must certainly be set within 4 clock cycles of each other, right?

I then read from the EEPROM as follows:

```c
U8_T eeprom_read_byte(void* address)
{
    cli();
    /* Wait for previous write to complete */
    while (TRUE == EECR.bits.EEPE) {
    }

    /* Set up read */
    EEAR.byte = (U8_T) address;
    /* Enable read */
    EECR.bits.EERE = TRUE;

    sei();

    return EEDR.byte;
}
```

But I get back only `0xFF`! The **erased** value! The datasheet says that EEPM0 and EEPM1 set to 0 should erase-and-write. But no writing appears to take place. Any ideas?

I've tried compiling with -O2 with no result. Another post told me to use -O3, but -O3 breaks my program (linker fails). Anyway I work in aerospace and optimizations are forbidden, so it must work without them.

Registers are defined as follows:

```c
/** EEPROM Control Register */
typedef union {
    struct {
        /** EEPROM Read Enable */
        VBOOL_T EERE        : 1;
        /** EEPROM Write Enable */
        VBOOL_T EEPE        : 1;
        /** EEPROM Master Write Enable */
        VBOOL_T EEMPE       : 1;
        /** EEPROM Ready Interrupt Enable */
        VBOOL_T EERIE       : 1;
        /** EEPROM Mode Bits */
        VBOOL_T EEPM0       : 1;
        VBOOL_T EEPM1       : 1;
        VBOOL_T Reserved6   : 1;
        VBOOL_T Reserved7   : 1;
    } bits;
    VU8_T byte;
} EECR_T;
/** EEPROM Control Register */
extern volatile EECR_T EECR;
```

Comment: You have a function parameter of `void* address` which means it is a point to the address, to get the content from the address, it should be `*(uint16_t*)address);`, not `(U8_T) address;`.

Comment: A driver should _never_ touch the global interrupt mask `cli`/`sei`. Particularly not by destroying its previous value as this code does. An EEPROM driver _may_ be allowed to do that, but only if it ends the whole write session by resetting the MCU.

Comment: "Anyway I work in aerospace and optimizations are forbidden" As is using hobbyist AVR for anything more critical than airport vending machines, pretty much... This MCU family is notoriously infamous for it's very poor EMI immunity and has been so for well over 20 years.

Comment: You guys are incredibly rude. Yes it's a hobby project. I'm not an aerospace software engineer. I'm learning from them.

Comment: @Lundin so can you explain this comment in the ATmega328P datasheet? "Caution: An interrupt between step 5 and step 6 will make the write cycle fail, since the EEPROM master write enable will time-out. If an interrupt routine accessing the EEPROM is interrupting another EEPROM access, the EEAR or EEDR register will be modified, causing the interrupted EEPROM access to fail. It is recommended to have the global interrupt flag cleared during all the steps to avoid these problems."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this part, but the manual 13.6.4 describes the procedure:

> 1. Wait until EEPE becomes zero.
> 2. Wait until SPMEN in SPMCSR becomes zero.
> 3. Write new EEPROM address to EEAR (optional).
> 4. Write new EEPROM data to EEDR (optional).
> 5. Write a '1' to the EEMPE bit while writing a zero to EEPE in EECR.
> 6. Within four clock cycles after setting EEMPE, write a '1' to EEPE.

1. OK.
2. You don't do this.
3. You do this but only to the ls byte EEARL. Meaning if the address is larger than the eeprom offset 256, your code will not work since you don't write to EEARH. Or if there's stray values left behind in EEARH, your program will go bananas.
4. OK.
5. Hmm. You are using the not recommended bit-field feature of C. I'm not sure if `EECR.bits.EERE = TRUE;` will result in a byte instruction or a bit instruction on the assembler level. In case of the latter, EEPE will not get written to zero as the manual says it should be.

   Recommended practice is to never use bit-fields, instead write to the whole register at once so you are sure that EEPE will get set.
6. Yes it seems reasonable that there is no 4 clock cycle delay before `EECR.bits.EEPE = TRUE;` is executed. But again this depends on what all the bit-field goo results in. Maybe in the worst case something gets translated into read into register, modify register, write register sequence. In which case far more than 4 clock cycles are executed.

The key to understanding what's going on is to view the disassembly of the program, to see what's actually generated. AVR asm is easy enough to read even for one like me who have never used it.

---

Unrelated to that, you have another severe bug in the driver. A driver should *never* touch the global interrupt mask `cli`/`sei`. Particularly not by destroying its previous value as this code does. If you ever touch these registers you need to stack the CCR and restore it afterwards.

An EEPROM driver *may* be allowed to disable all interrupts, but only if it ends the whole write session by resetting the MCU.

It is common practice to enter EEPROM programming through a safe mode, where all interrupts are disabled before programming is commenced. And once it is done, the MCU is rebooted with waiting for the wdog or by writing an incorrect sequence to its register.

Re-starting execution where it was previously after an EEPROM update is dangerous practice, since all parts of the program aren't necessarily fetching values from the EEPROM continuously.

Comment: From the datasheet: "Step 2 is only relevant if the software contains a boot
loader allowing the CPU to program the flash. If the flash is never being updated by the CPU, step 2 can be omitted." This code doesn't run at any time when the flash is being updated so I figured I could omit it. Points 3, 5, and 6 seem very relevant and I will follow up on them! Thanks